# How can I query the current orientation of an iPhone/iPad screen?

Tags: iphone, ipad, screen-orientation

I was curious to know if there is some way to determine the orientation of a screen on iPhone/iPad.

Currently I find myself setting a member variable when this message is called:

```
- (BOOL)shouldAutorotateToInterfaceOrientation:(UIInterfaceOrientation)interfaceOrientation {
   self.orientation = interfaceOrientation;
   return YES;
}
```

... which feels like something I should be able to query as a state instead of having to track it when it changes.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

UIViewController has the interfaceOrientation property.

Don't get confused by orientation in UIDevice, which is not the orientation of the interface, but the physical orientation.

Comment: That is a subtle but important distinction.  Thanks for the answer.

Comment: depreciated in iOS8. Docs recommend: `viewWillTransitionToSize:withTransitionCoordinator:`

Answer (score 11):

Use this if you have a status bar on top.

```
UIInterfaceOrientation orientation = [[UIApplication sharedApplication] statusBarOrientation];
if (orientation == UIInterfaceOrientationPortrait || orientation == UIInterfaceOrientationPortraitUpsideDown) {
    // portrait             
} else {
    // landscape
}
```

Comment: Does it returns the orientation of my `UIView` ?

Answer (score 1):

You can do `[[UIDevice currentDevice] orientation]`.

Comment: This is *not* the correct way for interface orientation. From the manual: "The orientation property uses these constants to identify the device orientation. These constants identify the physical orientation of the device and are not tied to the orientation of your application’s user interface."